# Combinatorics, probability exercise

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have a couple of combinatorics and probability problems that I have so much uncertainty when solving. My concepts are not that clear. Please shed me some light

1a You throw two dice. Whats the probability that the sum is 8 and none of the dice shows a 1.

my attempt: 5/36

b. You have a coin you like to toss when you feel bored. Today your boredom corresponds to 8 throws in a row. Whats the probability, that you get exactly 4 times heads, under the constraint that
within the first 4 tosses there must be 2 heads already.
How about the case in which there must be 3 heads within the first 4 tosses?

my attempt: 2 heads already: (2^4/2^8)/(2^6/2^8) = 1/4

In the following games the experiment is repeated until a certain condition is met. We note down the
outcomes as strings. Denote the probability that a game lasts exactly N rounds (≥ 0).
1

a) You toss a coin. Heads is denoted by 0, tails by 1. The game is over when we toss
heads for the second time (e.g. 111011111110).

my attempt: NC2 * (1/2)^2 * (1/2)*(N-2) = NC2 * (1/2)^N

b)  Same game, but the game stops if we toss heads for the k-th time (k ≤ N)

my attempt: NCk * (1/2)^k * (1/2)*(N-k) = NCk * (1/2)^N

c)  We throw one dice. The game stops if the sum of the throws is dividable by 6.

d) We throw two dice. The game stops if both dice show the same number.

my attempt: i don't even know how to start please help

Calculate the expectation value of the following random experiments. You throw a dice and note down
the value and you are done. But if you throw a six, you throw once more and add the values. If the
throw after the six is again a six, you throw again and add the three throws up and so on. Calculate the
expectation value of the following random experiments if

a)  you stop the game if you have the third six in a row.

my attempt: (1/6)^3 x 18

b)  you go on arbitrarily long in case you throw sixes. Hint: Use the fact that Summation(i = 0->∞)
xi =1/1−x
and Summation(i = 0->∞) ixi = x/(1−x)^2 for −1 < x < 1.

my attempt: (1/6)^n * 6n, using the second formula with i = n, answer = 36/25

Comment: For probability it takes $N$ rounds until we get the second head, we need $1$ head in the first $N-1$ rounds and then a head. Probability is $\binom{N}{1}(1/2)^{N-1}(1/2)$, which is $N/2^N$. About other questions, there are too many. The last few are a little less standard.

Comment: Throw two dice, stop when they show the same number. The probability of same number is $1/6$. So probability different is $5/6$. We stop at $N$ if different $N-1$ times in a row then equal, probability $(5/6)^{N-1}(1/6)$.

Comment: For throwing two dice every time, the last attempt has to be the same, so isn't that (1/6)^2 instead?

Comment: Both dice show the same number if they show $(1,1)$ (prob. $1/36$) or $(2,2)$ (prob $1/36$), and so on. Add up. We get $6/36$, that is, $1/6$. Or to think of it another way, whatever number we get on the green die, the probability the number matches it is $1/6$.

Comment: Thanks, i get what you mean.
Can you help me with 1b and the expectation value question? I am particularly unsure about these two. Thanks

Comment: I don't know for sure what 1b says. In the first four tosses there are exactly $2$ heads? If so you need $2$ heads in the last four tosses, probability is $\binom{4}{2}/2^4$. Or does it mean in the first four tosses there are **at least** $2$ heads. Then it is more complicated.  About the expectation questions, I feel awkward about answering only a small fraction from a too large collection of questions.

Comment: I think it should be, given that the first 4 tosses have exactly 2 heads, the probability of having four heads in 8 tosses, i am not sure about how to do it as it involves ordering

I am sorry for having too large collection of questions but these two should be my greatest problems

Comment: Well, if so I have solved it. And given (exactly) three heads in first four is even easier, $\binom{4}{1}/2^4$.

Comment: But you have not divided it by the condition of the of having the first 2 heads in the first 4 tosses did you?

Comment: No need to divide, the conditional probability was calculated directly. One could I guess multiply and  divide by the probability of $2$ in the first four.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We look at the expectation questions only.

With probability $1/6$, we get a second round. With probability $(1/6)^2$, we get a third round. On any round, the expected gain is $7/2$, so if the game cuts off at the third round, the expected gain is
$$(7/2)\left(1+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6^2}\right).$$

The case where an arbitrary number of rounds is allowed can be done in a similar way, by summing a simple infinite series.  But we instead condition on the result of the first round.

Let our expectation be $e$. With probability $5/6$, our expectation is $3$. With probability $1/6$ it is $6+e$. Thus
$$e=(5/6)(3)+(1/6)(6+e).$$
Solve. We get $e=21/5$.

Comment: I don't understand. I know the expected value for a throw is 7/2. But what is the second part? 1 is because first throw must happen, 1/6 is the chance of the second throw for happening am i right?
So it is actually the expected value of an expected value?

Comment: The second part does not need the use of the equations?
I thought the expected value should go as follows: probability of throwing three 6s * the sum, (1/6)^3 * 18, why is it wrong?

Comment: Expectation of an expectation is a good description. The technical term is that we used a conditional expectation argument. The second part could have been done as an infinite sum $(7/2)(1+1/6+1/6^2+\cdots)$, same answer, I used the linear equation argument for variety.